# How to put a string resulting from json_encode() into a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$array =array();
array_push($array,"string");
$string = json_encode($array);

mysql_query('UPDATE table SET strings="'.$string.'" WHERE username="'.$username.'"');
```

The string is not appearing inthe mysql-table. When I use 'INT' Numbers per when I define a string like $string = "string" it works. So somehow it has to do with the json_encode() function.

Can somebody help me with this. What is happening with my string inside of json_encode(), why is the string not suitable for the mysql table ?

Comment: Things are not being escaped properly, because you are using old `mysql_query` look into `PDO` and prepared statements with `mysqli`

Comment: Your Code works for me. The result is for me ["string"] Can you post the parsed query_string?

Comment: Invert the quotes,single quotes outside,double inside

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqli or PDO (mysqli is shown, as it's most likely easier to implement for your existing app)

Chances are, the json encode is adding characters that break your SQL syntax.  You'll need to escape the string that you insert:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE table SET 
    strings='".mysqli::real_escape_string($string)."' 
    WHERE username='".mysqli::real_escape_string($username)."'");
```

You must ALWAYS escape strings, or cast to `(int)`, `(float)`, etc. to avoid syntax problems and SQL injection.  Or use prepared statements.  Both mysqli and PDO support prepared statements.

For beginning SQL application development, I usually recommend going with string building, like you have here, as it is easier for folks to understand.  However, once you have experience under your belt, and a good handle on SQL, I recommend looking in to moving over to prepared statements.

There are plenty of articles all over detailing how to use prepared statements, and the dangers of SQL injection.